# I can't find what's wrong with my micro bit code, variables are not found even if i have specified them

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

i'm trying to code a simple game inside micro:bit with python,
this is the code:

```
def on_button_pressed_a():
    global imput_navicella22, navicella2
    if imput_navicella22 == 0:
        imput_navicella22 += 1
        navicella2 = game.create_sprite(0, 2)
        music.play_melody("D F G C5 E B G C5 ", 110)
        basic.pause(1000)
        navicella2.move(1)
        basic.pause(1000)
        navicella2.move(1)
        navicella2.set(LedSpriteProperty.Y, 2)
        navicella2.turn(Direction.RIGHT, 90)
        
        def on_button_pressed_a():
            global imput_navicella22
            if imput_navicella22 == 1:
                imput_navicella22 = 2
                
                def on_forever():
                    asteroide2 = game.create_sprite(4, Math.random_range(0, 4))
                    asteroide2.turn(Direction.RIGHT, 180)
                    for index in range(4):
                        basic.pause(velocita)
                        asteroide2.move(1)
                    asteroide2.delete()
                basic.forever(on_forever)
        input.on_button_pressed(Button.A, on_button_pressed_a)
                
            
    def on_forever2():
        if imput_navicella22 != 0:
            global navicella2
            navicella2.set(LedSpriteProperty.Y, 2)
            if abs(pitch) > 10:
                basic.pause(300)
                navicella2.change(LedSpriteProperty.Y, 1)
            if abs(pitch) > -10:
                basic.pause(300)
                navicella2.change(LedSpriteProperty.Y, -1)
    basic.forever(on_forever2)
input.on_button_pressed(Button.A, on_button_pressed_a)

def on_gesture_shake():
    control.reset()
input.on_gesture(Gesture.SHAKE, on_gesture_shake)

navicella2: game.LedSprite = None
imput_navicella22 = 0
velocita2 = 0
sprite = None
pitch = input.rotation(Rotation.PITCH)
velocita = 2000
```

but here:

```
def on_forever2():
        if imput_navicella22 != 0:
            global navicella2
            navicella2.set(LedSpriteProperty.Y, 2)
            if abs(pitch) > 10:
                basic.pause(300)
                navicella2.change(LedSpriteProperty.Y, 1)
            if abs(pitch) > -10:
                basic.pause(300)
                navicella2.change(LedSpriteProperty.Y, -1)
    basic.forever(on_forever2)
```

it says that *can't find called function "navicella2.change"* and *unknown object type; cannot lookup attribute 'set'* and *'change'*

but i specified the variable *"navicella2"* before here:

```
navicella2 = game.create_sprite(0, 2)
```

and here:

```
navicella2.set(LedSpriteProperty.Y, 2)
```

what's wrong with my code?
where do i need to change it?

Comment: Did you use some example code Biz? I have not programmed a micro:bit in python but why do you declare `on_button_pressed_a` as a new function inside of your original function `on_button_pressed_a`?

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that the error didn’t pop up, but variable names can’t have numbers in them.

It says `unknown object type` because it won't accept the numerical characters in the variable name. Try to write the numbers as names like `twentytwo`.